# Material/style for a BB-safe fence

Tags: fence

My neighbors placed a BB gun target on the border between our properties. They shoot at it from their property. They miss sometimes, especially when they've been drinking or toking. I don't mind BBs occasionally going onto my property, and there's no place else they can put the target without there being risk to their cars or houses.

I've decided it's time to put a fence between our properties - not because of BBs, but because the neighbors are peeing on my lawn. I want to minimize potential injury if they fire a BB that hits (and possibly bounces off of) the fence.

What type of fence would you recommend?

Comment: For the peeing, suggest a nice powerful electric fence.  Your neighbours should put up a large stop for the BBs, but with  the drinking and toking would suggest a solid wood fence.

Comment: Do you also want to minimize injury when they pee on your lawn?  I can think of solutions, though possibly not legal, that would never deflect a BB back at them but would make peeing on your lawn excruciatingly painful.

Comment: In some places there are rules (county, city, homeowner association) that restrict the type or height of fences. So need to figure out the limits first and then build within those limits. Also need to figure out *exactly* where your property line is, because you don't want to get into a situation of building a fence and getting the neighbors mad (they will be, when they're sober enough to think about it) and then find out it is 6" onto their property. **Property lines are not always where you think they are**.

Comment: Go with a solid metal fence. It will help them improve accuracy or learn about the fun of ricochets.

Comment: Who cares? If they shoot at a fence that ricochets BBs, that's their bad judgment and their problem.  That's how gun law liability works.   You didn't cause the BB to ricochet by building the fence.

Answer (score 3):

You're being an *exceedingly* tolerant neighbor; perhaps a bit **too** tolerant - I expect that existing laws prohibit both of those actions by your neighbors. It's not neighborly of them.

Normal construction of a BB-trap target (which is essentially what you're asking your fence to do) is to angle it so that the BBs are deflected into the ground. To do that on your side of the line, you'll have to give up some of your land.

Comment: From OP's perspective, it really doesn't matter if the fence bounces the BBs up or down. If the neighbor doesn't like BBs bouncing back at them, that's **their** problem, and they can build a proper target on their own property. As far as the laws, that gets tricky. While it shouldn't be that way, calling the cops on them might push the neighbors to do something really stupid - with potentially bad consequences for both OP and the neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hedge.**

1. Hedges look better than any fence.  They might make flowers!
2. Pee will make hedge grow thicker.
3. Hedge does not say "I am your neighbor fencing you out".   Hedge says "I am a neighbor beautifying my property."
4. Hedge can slow down BB but BB will not bounce back.
5. Local nursery will be enthusiastic to sell you plants appropriate for your area which will turn into a hedge.